# CSS descendant selector - anchor element in beginning of descendant list breaks styling

Tags: css, selector, descendant

I'm trying to apply styling for only the `p` and `a` elements that are a descendant of any element with class "some-class".  Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list, the code below should provide the expected behavior.  However, the styling is unexpectedly being applied to **all** the `p` elements.  Interestingly, I am able to get the correct behavior if I reorder the list of descendants, i.e. `.some-class p,a`. Can someone explain why this might be?

FYI - I've run the code in both Firefox and Chrome with the same results.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.some-class a,p {
     color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>should not be red</p>
</div>

<div class="some-class">
    <p>should be red</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect you may be misinterpreting what the comma does in the selector line you have shown. It is not a combinator, but a space is. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: I should have stated that I want the styling to apply to all p and a elements that are descendants of some-class.  I'll edit the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select all `a`-elements that are inside elements with a classname of `some-class`, then you select all `p`-elements. You must specify that you also want to select all `p`-elements that are inside elements with a classname of `some-class`, like this:

```css
.some-class a,
.some-class p {
   color: red;
}
```

And a more modern way of doing the same:

```css
.some-class :is(a,p) {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks rehnoj.  I thought I read the documentation carefully, but I may have missed this detail.